# Swift UI - Animating individual views in a gridstack

Tags: button, view, swiftui, action

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

I have a GridStack view which generates an array of views. See below:

```
struct GridStack<Content: View> : View {
    let rows :Int
    let columns : Int
    let content : (Int, Int) -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(0 ..< rows){ row in
                HStack{
                    ForEach(0 ..< columns){ column in
                        self.content(row, column)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I currently have this working code which sends the array's value into the integer variable 'upTo' in my main code:

```
GridStack(rows: 3, columns: 4){ rows, cols in
          Button(action: {
                 upTo = rows * 4 + cols + 1
          }, label: {
                 Text("Number \(rows * 4 + cols + 1)")
          })
}
```

I would like to make this Text animate however if I add animations to the Text directly, every one of the texts moves on tapping where I would **only** like to animate the one that I am clicking.

I have tried to make the text into a Button view and pass it into the main button's label but apparently embedding buttons is a crime punishable by death.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You try to put button into button - in SwiftUI, which is reactive, only one works, which reacts first. Why would one want to do that?

Comment: You are nesting buttons? That is not a good idea, as the system won't know which button to activate. Also you are creating two instances of your `test` view in the `Cententview`.

Comment: Is there not a way to tell the system to activate both the buttons?

Comment: Sounds rather like a [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. As the other said and you experienced, nesting buttons is not a good idea. Wouldn't it be more suitable to put the animation stuff within a `onTapGesture` view modifier?

Comment: Here's a nice updated question for you all, hopefully it brings more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think two solutions are feasible. Please see my working examples below.

Would you like the applied effect to persist after clicking the button? In this case, I would recommend to create a custom view which stores the state.

```swift
struct GridStack<Content: View> : View {
    let rows :Int
    let columns : Int
    let content : (Int, Int) -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(0 ..< rows){ row in
                HStack{
                    ForEach(0 ..< columns){ column in
                        self.content(row, column)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyCustomView: View {
    let upTo: Int
    let callback: () -> Void
    
    @State var animate = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.callback()
            self.animate.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Number \(self.upTo)")
                .background(self.animate ? Color.red : Color.white)
                .animation(.linear(duration: 1.0))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @State var upTo: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(self.upTo)")

            GridStack(rows: 3, columns: 4) { rows, cols in
                MyCustomView(upTo: rows * 4 + cols + 1, callback: {
                    self.upTo = rows * 4 + cols + 1
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView2()
    }
}
```

Otherwise a custom button style will do. In this case you are able to access the configuration's `isPressed` property.

```swift
struct GridStack<Content: View> : View {
    let rows :Int
    let columns : Int
    let content : (Int, Int) -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(0 ..< rows){ row in
                HStack{
                    ForEach(0 ..< columns){ column in
                        self.content(row, column)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyCustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(configuration.isPressed ? Color.red : Color.white)
            .animation(.linear(duration: 1.0))
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @State var upTo: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(self.upTo)")

            GridStack(rows: 3, columns: 4) { rows, cols in
                Button(action: {
                    self.upTo = rows * 4 + cols + 1
                }) {
                    Text("Number \(rows * 4 + cols + 1)")
                }
                .buttonStyle(MyCustomButtonStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView2()
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks again Nikolai. I used the first example as the second is a bit beyond me. To be honest I don't really understand what role the callback variable plays? Is it a variable? And is that what allows ContentView2 to read the value chosen when a button is pressed?

Comment: You're welcome! The button is wrapped inside the `MyCustomView` view. Your goal is to perform an action by clicking on the button. But in fact that the integer state `upTo` is not accessible from within `MyCustomView`, a closure which "describes" what to do is passed from `ContentView2`. And finally, this closure is called by the button's action closure. Read more about closures [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html).

Comment: Ok I'll practice my closures! It's a bit desperate, but could you have a look at my other question on my profile regarding element wise multiplication of some arrays? Something about my calculating the arrays is turning them into an Any operand which means I can't multiply elements of the array.